# Cannot hide "Attach to Case" action in Article Case Feed tool

Tags: case, page-layout, service-cloud-console, articles, casefeed

In the console, the articles displayed in Articles Case Feed tool has two actions, "**Email article as a PDF**" and "**Attach to Case**".

[image]

I can control the "**Email article as a PDF**" action by selecting/deselecting the checkbox in the Articles Tool Settings in Feed View Page Layout.

[image]

I couldn't find a checkbox or any other option for "**Attach to Case**" action. Is there any way to hide that? Thanks

Comment: I am looking for the same solution. Found this article: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000249228&type=1&language=en_US Attempted to **Dis**able Attaching Articles Inline by deselecing the option but that did not work. Other suggestions?